# Vim doesn't allow me to type in numbers

Tags: macos, vim, vnc-viewer

I'm having difficulty using Vim. When I attempt to type in numbers it just adds a character about what I'm trying to type.

[image: Vim picture example]

Here, I've pressed "2" and it moves up and adds an r. Number "1" adds q and moves up a line as well. I've been googling for solutions and am kind of lost at this point. Insert mode is enabled, as shown at the bottom.

Additionally, I've tried enabling and disabling number lock and using the number pad as well.

Number lock off -> number pad only responds with Home, End, Pg Up, Pg Dn.
Number lock on -> number pad responds the same as above.

I've tried hitting control, mac key, and alt in the hopes that one of them were toggled, but I still get the same issue after hitting them once.

**Note**: Using VNC Viewer to connect.

Inputs are set to enabled and to pass media keys and special keys directly to VNC server.

Comment: probably a terminal setting, making it think you have a completely different keyboard than what's physically present.

Comment: Is this a Vim setting? I invoked vim through bash, and numbers worked fine there.

Comment: Did you test by launching `$ vim -u NONE`, to be sure no special config is loaded?

Comment: Just tried it, still getting letters and new lines being inserted when I hit any number key (above letters and on numpad)

Comment: Did you checked whether numbers or their terminal codes are mapped to some other keys?

Answer (score 0):

You can find some help (though not straightforward) here in wikia : 
http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/PuTTY_numeric_keypad_mappings

at the bottom of the article, there is some comments related to VNC.
Hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

Do not use the numbers on the right hand side of the keyboard, instead use the ones above the letters.

Comment: I've tried those as well, and get the same results.